# Как записать в формате Swagger / OpenAPI такие параметры

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi

Делаю схему сваггера, но не понимаю как правильно указать параметры фильтрации для пакета  [Laravel query builder](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v2/features/filtering).

Вот пример:

`/users?filter[name]=john&filter[email]=gmail`

Как записать схему для `filter[name]=john&filter[email]=gmail`? Я сделал набросок, но проблема в том, что `filter` используется дважды и не понятно как работать с `[...]`

```
paths:
  /users
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/filter"

components:
  parameters:
    filter:
    name: filter
    in: query
    required: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В OpenAPI 3.0 такой параметр описывается как объект, который сериализуется как [`style: deepObject`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query). В данном случае `filter` - имя параметра, `name` и `email` - свойства объекта.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

paths:
  /users:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          style: deepObject
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              email:
                type: string
                format: email
```

> получается
>
> ```
> filter%5Bname%5D=string&filter%5Bemail%5D=user%40example.com
> ```
>
> а должно быть
>
> ```
> filter[name]=string&filter[email]=user%40example.com
> ```

Получается как раз правильно. Согласно [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986/) символы `[ ]` в незакодированном виде могут использоваться только в [IPv6-адресах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers), например

```
http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html
```

Во всех других местах в URI эти символы должны быть percent-encoded: `[` -> `%5B`, `]` -> `%5D`. Подробнее тут:
[Is array syntax using square brackets in URL query strings valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490326/113116)

Сервер при обработке запроса должен раскодировать `%5B` и `%5D` обратно в `[` `]`. (Если сервер так не делает, значит он нарушает RFC-стандарт.)

Если вы используете [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) для показа документации, то можно добавить в него код, который будет менять `%5B` и `%5D` на `[` `]` в URL'ах в cURL-командах для читабельности. Для этого в коде Swagger UI-страницы (например, `index.html`) найдите блок `SwaggerUIBundle` и добавьте в него вот такой `requestInterceptor`:

```js
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "...",
        ...

        requestInterceptor: (req) => {
          req.url = req.url
            .replace('%5B', '[')
            .replace('%5D', ']');

          // curl'у нужен флаг -g, если в URL'е символы [ ] незакодированы
          req.curlOptions = ['-g'];

          return req;
        }
      })
```

Для этого нужен Swagger UI версии 3.35.0 или позднее.

Comment: К сожалению, нет, получается `filter%5Bname%5D=string&filter%5Bemail%5D=user%40example.com` а должно быть `filter[name]=string&filter[email]=user%40example.com`

Comment: @TotalPusher добавила ответ в сам пост

Comment: Да, логично. urldecode так и сделал. Чуть позже проверю окончательно. Спасибо, что подсказали.

Comment: Если добавить allowReserved: true, `[]` и прочие зарезервированные не будут преобразоваться в % нотацию

Answer (score 1):

Думаю как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491688/how-to-define-parameters-with-square-brackets-in-openapi-swagger)

```
swagger: '2.0'
...
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter[name]
          type: string
        - in: query
          name: filter[email]
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```